# Passing char as int

Tags: c#

Could someone explain me why is this happening and how can i avoid it in future.

I had two functions like this:

```
public static int Result(int x, int y)
{
    return x * y;
}

public static int Result(int x, char Anything)
{
    if(Anything.Equals('M'))
        return x * x;
    else
        return x;
}

int r = Result(2, 2); // Returns 4
int r1 = Result(2, 'T'); // Returns 2
int r2 = Result(2, 'M'); // Returns 4
```

As you can see methods have same names but different parameters and displays results above which is expected.

What made me problem is when i changed `public static int Result(int x, char Anything)` to `public static int Result(int x, char[] Anything)`

Reason this made me problem is that for some reason my complex function was returning me error all time AFTER compiling and trying to use it. After few hours i found out that change was giving me a problem.

Since i changed that method to take `char[]` instead of `char` it was logic for `Visual Studio` to tell me `cannot convert char to char[]` BUT because i had other function which get `int, int` and i had `int, char` passed it didn't return me error.

As i guess reason for this is because each `char` has it's numeric value, and as i changed other function, compiler went to see other methods with same name and found one with `int, int` but he COULD convert from `char` to `int` and because of that it didn't give me error.

My side question is am i right with this guess?
My main question is how could i prevent this from happening. I had this function used about 50 times and 20 of them were ones who needed to change and instead of popping error and just selecting it i had to go to each of 50 and see myself if it needs change.

Comment: So your question is why accepts `public static void Result(int x){}` this call `Result('M');`

Comment: Perhaps you *shouldn't* use the same method name when the methods do different things? A `char` can be cast to int implicitly

Comment: I still don't understand what happened from your description. Does the compiler throw an error that you _"cannot convert char to char[]"_ or does it work but you get a wrong result?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is correct. There is an implicit conversion between `char` and `int`, as documented in [Implicit numeric conversions table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table)

Comment: @PatrickHofman: yes, but OP says that he got an error: _"was returning me error all time AFTER compiling"_ and _"Visual Studio tells me it cannot convert char to char[]"_

Comment: Okay. Misunderstood your comment then @TimSchmelter

Comment: @TimSchmelter *after* changing the signature to `char[]`. The question contains the original code, not the one that actually shows the problem or the results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: ok, but when you change the signature to `char[]` you don't get a compiler error because there is still the overload that takes an `int`

Comment: @TimSchmelter not the clearest question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It feels like your design is flawed, or at least your method names, but it might just be the over-simplification. The solution here is to use the `params` option. It still matches a character to the `int, char[]` signature.

```
public static int Result(int x, params char[] Anything)
{
    if (Anything.Contains('M'))
        return x * x;
    else
        return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not much you can do here. Yes, that happens because of the implicit conversion.

To catch those mistakes early, you could achieve a good code coverage with your unit tests. Seeing some tests fail and seeing that your method with the `char[]` is no longer covered at all would lead you to the problem very quickly, instead of finding out after hours of debugging.